# Ionic2/Angular2 - ModalView does not open when trying to fetch data from a RestAPI

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to show data that I fetched using a rest API inside a modal on an Ionic2 app; however, when I click to open the modal it does not appear. The weird part is that when I remove the code that fetches the data, the modal shows up again!
Here is the **non-working** code:

**modalPage.js**

```
export class modalPage {
      static get parameters() {
        return [[ViewController],[Http]];
      }

      constructor(viewCtrl) {
        this.viewCtrl = viewCtrl;
        this.http = http;
        this.res = null;

        this.http._defaultOptions.headers.append('X-Parse-Application-Id', 'someKey');
        this.http._defaultOptions.headers.append('X-Parse-REST-API-Key', 'someKey');
        this.http.get('https://parseapi.server.com/classes/Sbt').subscribe(data => {
        this.res = data.json().results;
        });

      }
        close() {
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
      }
    }
```

**When I remove** few lines from the code above (mainly from **constructor()**), **it works**

```
    export class modalPage {
      static get parameters() {
        return [[ViewController],[Http]];
      }

      constructor(viewCtrl) {
        this.viewCtrl = viewCtrl;
      }
        close() {
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
      }
    }
```

Comment: How does the `ViewController` look like (HTML and code)?

Comment: Where is defined http variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure, there is something wrong with your REST API, you don't get results, that's why the modal does not open. What made me sure is that when you remove the lines that fetches data from the REST API everything works again!
I believe you were NOT able to see any error in the console, that's why you were stuck!

That's the big issue I am facing with Angular, I am not able to debug and see errors as I go...I hope in the near future to see errors in the console instead of seeing a blank page or simply no response from the Angular side.

What I recommend you is to re-check with you REST API, simply via CURL on your terminal, so you can catch the error!

I hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting same issue, here it should load modal first and then we can request for HTTP, please try with setTimeout(), it's works for me.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.onLoad();
}, 500);

onLoad() {
    //this.http request
}
```